# Hierarchical data store

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

I have two tables first main table that stores all the objects and second relationship table that stores parent-child relationship that spans across multi-level.

main table : `table1`

| object_id | object_column1 | object_column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| parent_1 | some_value | some_value |
| parent_2 | some_value | some_value |
| child_1 | some_value | some_value |
| child_2 | some_value | some_value |
| child_3 | some_value | some_value |
| child_4 | some_value | some_value |
| child_5 | some_value | some_value |

relation table : `table2`

| parent_id | child_id | relation_column1 | relation_column2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| parent_1 | child_1 | has_list_value | has_string_value |
| parent_1 | child_2 | has_list_value |  |
| child_2 | child_3 |  | has_string_value |
| child_2 | child_4 | has_list_value | has_string_value |
| child_3 | child_5 |  |  |

In both Oracle and SQL Server DB to extract all level data have used `WITH Clause`.
In Spanner how can this be achieved?

Tried interleave table but that does not help much on the above tables as main table to relation table only solves one level and not the hierarchical all-level retrieval. Querying recursively is causing performance overhead.

Has anyone come across this and/or found a solution to this scenario?

Comment: It is not completely clear to me exactly what it is that you want to achieve. Would you mind giving a working example of a query in SQL Server / Oracle of what it is that you are trying to achieve? You mention the WITH clause in SQL Server/ Oracle. WITH is also supported in Cloud Spanner: https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/query-syntax#with_clause

Answer (score 0):

The best option with Spanner is to use interleaved tables and query with `JOIN`.

Interleaving tables will ensure that parent and child are stored on the same node. This will reduce the amount of communication between nodes when reading both parent and child.

The simplest way to write the query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM Parent
JOIN Child ON Parent.id = Child.id;
```

> NOTE: Parent data will be duplicated for each Child data.